# How do I collect all my Django data from the database before invoking my serializer?

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, many-to-many, django-serializer

I'm using Python 3.9 and Django 3.2.  I have a Django model with a couple of many-to-many relationsips

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address, through='CoopAddressTags')
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    proposed_changes = models.JSONField("Proposed Changes", null=True)
    reject_reason = models.TextField(null=True)
```

I can search for my model using a manager class that builds a query like so ...

```
    def find(
        self,
        partial_name,
        types_arr=None,
        enabled=None,
        city=None,
        zip=None,
        street=None,
        state_abbrev=None
    ):
        """
        Lookup coops by varying criteria.
        """
        q = Q()
        if partial_name:
            q &= Q(name__icontains=partial_name)
        if enabled != None:
            q &= Q(enabled=enabled)
        if types_arr != None:
            filter = Q(
                *[('types__name', type) for type in types_arr],
                _connector=Q.OR
            )
            q &= filter
        if street != None:
            q &= Q(addresses__raw__icontains=street)
        if city != None:
            q &= Q(addresses__locality__name__iexact=city)
        if zip != None:
            q &= Q(addresses__locality__postal_code=zip)
        if state_abbrev != None:
            q &= Q(addresses__locality__state__code=state_abbrev)
            q &= Q(addresses__locality__state__country__code="US")

        queryset = Coop.objects.filter(q)
        print(queryset.query)
        return queryset
```

In my view, I invoke and return the data using

```
coops = Coop.objects.find(...)
serializer = CoopSearchSerializer(coops, many=True)
```

in which the serializer looks like

```
class CoopSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['coopaddresstags_set'] = CoopAddressTagsSerializer(instance.coopaddresstags_set.all(), many=True).data
        return rep
```

What I'm noticing is when I search for a result set that contains 6 results, and each one is serialized using the logic above, I get a proportional number of queries run for each result ...

```
 SELECT "directory_coopaddresstags"."id", "directory_coopaddresstags"."coop_id", "directory_coopaddresstags"."address_id", "directory_coopaddresstags"."is_public" FROM "directory_coopaddresstags" WHERE "directory_coopaddresstags"."coop_id" = 271; args=(271,)
(0.000) SELECT "directory_coopaddresstags"."id", "directory_coopaddresstags"."coop_id", "directory_coopaddresstags"."address_id", "directory_coopaddresstags"."is_public" FROM "directory_coopaddresstags" WHERE "directory_coopaddresstags"."coop_id" = 271; args=(271,)
type of instance: <class 'directory.models.CoopAddressTags'>
(0.000) SELECT "address_address"."id", "address_address"."street_number", "address_address"."route", "address_address"."locality_id", "address_address"."raw", "address_address"."formatted", "address_address"."latitude", "address_address"."longitude" FROM "address_address" WHERE "address_address"."id" = 263 LIMIT 21; args=(263,)
(0.000) SELECT "address_locality"."id", "address_locality"."name", "address_locality"."postal_code", "address_locality"."state_id" FROM "address_locality" WHERE "address_locality"."id" = 16 LIMIT 21; args=(16,)
(0.000) SELECT "address_state"."id", "address_state"."name", "address_state"."code", "address_state"."country_id" FROM "address_state" WHERE "address_state"."id" = 19313 LIMIT 21; args=(19313,)
(0.000) SELECT "address_country"."id", "address_country"."name", "address_country"."code" FROM "address_country" WHERE "address_country"."id" = 484 LIMIT 21; args=(484,)
```

So if there are 6 results, the above gets run 6 times with different IDs.  Is there a way to only have a single set of queries run so taht regardless of whether there are 1, 10, or 100 results, the same number of queries gets run to return the data?

Comment: you should use ```prefetch_related``` and ```select_related``` in your queries, maybe this link will help you to understand the situation https://betterprogramming.pub/django-select-related-and-prefetch-related-f23043fd635d

Comment: ```prefetch_related``` documentation link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: ```select_related``` documentaion link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: I tried changing my line "queryset = Coop.objects.filter(q)" to "queryset = Coop.objects.filter(q).prefetch_related('addresses')" and this did nothing to reduce the number of queries executed.  Not sure if this has anything to do with the "through" keyword I use on my many-to-many relation but thought I'd put that out there.

Comment: You also need to add a prefetch for `coopaddresstags_set`, which you access once per instance in your serializer. So try to use `prefetch_related('addresses', 'coopaddresstags_set')`

Comment: Could you add what's in the `CoopAddressTagsSerializer`?

Answer (score 1):

I see, you collect your data from many M2M and FK relations.

I am agree with @Amres, you can use `prefetch_related` and `select_related` in your queries, but simply use of those methods can not help you.

## First:

With `prefetch_related` and `select_related` you can achieve 3 queries per request. Not lower. 1 big query and 2 for m2m relations.
More here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

## Second:

You can not use simply:

```
.prefetch_related('addresses')
```

It does nothing. In your case you need to use `Prefetch` object.
More here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

Why? Answer is - you have additional FK in Address model:

- addresses__raw,
- addresses__locality,
- addresses__locality__state,
- addresses__locality__state__country

How it can be declared:

```
addressPrefetcher = Prefetch('adresses', queryset=Address.objects.select_related('raw', 'locality', 'locality__state', 'locality__state__country'))
```

## After that

You can use this construction:

```
coops = Coop.objects.find(Your_query).select_related('phone', 'email').prefetch_related(addressPrefetcher, 'types')
```

If i really correct understand your models - you receive only 3 hits in DB, don't matter how many objects in `CoopSearchSerializer`. You can achieve only 1 hit with `GroupConcat`, but for this business case it is overhead.

p.s. Probably keep `phone` and `email` as FK, is a not good idea. But it is possible.

Comment: Am I passing the data to the serializer in the right way to utilize what you have done ('serializer = CoopSearchSerializer(coops, many=True)')?  It seems like the serializer is pulling all the data one instance at a time instead of using the prefetched data you have set up.

Comment: you should debug you project. I can not say why it is not works. But instance.coopaddresstags_set.all() - made a call to DB for every instance. Try to prefetch it. If it help to remove some queryes - it a sign: somewhere you have a wrong realization.